# Audit kernel module usage in Oracle

Tags: oracle, audit

In my continuing effort to bring my database up to a given standard, I need to ensure that all loading, unloading, and restarting of kernel modules are being audited. I have no idea what this thing is talking about or how I would go about auditing such a thing. This is one in a list of auditable events. Before the list begins, the standard claims that some may require OS settings to audit; I'm assuming this is one of them. Unfortunately, the people who may know are not easily accessible.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question can be answered without further details but some general thoughts:

- What kernel are you talking about? If it's the OS Kernel then there are a few different ways depending on your OS and/or your Linux distribution. And it's depends  on your job role - are you responsible for the database server's Os, too or are you just responsible for the database?
- Do you have some kind of monitoring software like e.g. EnterpriseManger/GridControl? If so, a lot of baselining and auditig can be done with this tool, but beware that there a a lot of features that require special licenses. Read the most recent licensing documentaition for that. Even if you don't use the tool itself (e.g. for integration in another monitoring tool) but want to query the underlying views, you have to buy the license.
- If database auditing is required have a look at the documentation for your database release. With 12c the unified auditing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In your $ORACLE_HOME directory, there is a sudbdirectory Opatch and there is the command Opatch there to run with a couple parameters redirected to a date/timestamped file that should satisfy audits of Oracle software:

```
Opatch lsinventory
OPatch lspatches
```

You can do a `Opatch -help` for details.